# How can i get full error stack into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to save my log erros, so i forced a undefined variable calls.

But when i try to parse the stack value to a string i don't get the full data of variable stack

Here is my funtion that is giving me the error..

```
async handle(httpRequest: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponse> {
        const response = await this.controller.handle(httpRequest)
        if (response.statusCode === 500) {
            const { stack } = response.body
            console.log('HERE', stack, typeof stack)
            console.log('HERE1', stack.toString())
            console.log('HERE2', String(stack))
            console.log('HERE3', JSON.stringify(stack))
            await this.logRepository.logError(stack)
        }
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    }
```

Here are the print of the results.

```
HERE TypeError: Cannot destructure property '_id' of 'account' as it is undefined.
    at AccountMongoRepository.add (/home/tugzera/code-courses/node/node-tdd-solid-clean/src/infra/db/mongodb/repositories/account/account.ts:10:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at DbAddAccount.add (/home/tugzera/code-courses/node/node-tdd-solid-clean/src/data/usecases/db-add-account.ts:15:27)
    at SignUpController.handle (/home/tugzera/code-courses/node/node-tdd-solid-clean/src/presentation/controllers/signup/signup.ts:32:26)
    at LogControllerDecorator.handle (/home/tugzera/code-courses/node/node-tdd-solid-clean/src/main/decorators/log/log.ts:15:26)
    at /home/tugzera/code-courses/node/node-tdd-solid-clean/src/main/adapters/express-route-adapter.ts:9:44 object
```

```
HERE1 TypeError: Cannot destructure property '_id' of 'account' as it is undefined.
```

```
HERE2 TypeError: Cannot destructure property '_id' of 'account' as it is undefined.]
```

```
HERE3 {}
```

If anyone can help me i will be very greatefull

Comment: `stack` might be an `Error` object instead of the actual stack. Try `stack.stack`.